# Restore from copy of SQL Server backup file produces invalid data error

Tags: sql-server, backup, errors, copy

We have an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 sitting in a DMZ.  When I back up one of its databases to a drive local to that server, then run a RESTORE VERIFYONLY against the backup file, it declares the backup set valid.

If I subsequently robocopy the backup file to a mapped drive, pointing to a server located in our domain, then run a RESTORE VERIFYONLY (or a full RESTORE DATABASE, for that matter) against the copied backup file, while connected to a SQL Server instance which is also in the domain (running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3), the subsequent RESTORE returns the following error message:

```
    Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Read on "<Backup file path>" failed: 13(The data is invalid.)
    Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

This happens consistently and is repeatable.  Anyone have any ideas as to what might be corrupting the copied backup file?  Does robocopy feature any validation flags that might be useful?  What's the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: How have you validated that the SQL Server service account can see and has sufficient access to the mapped drive? Mapped drivers are per user. Have you set up the same mapped drive for the service account? Why aren't you just using a UNC path (you still need to ensure that the SQL Server service account has access, but it's one less hoop)?

Comment: When I make the second restore attempt (while connected to the in-domain instance), I do reference the copied backup file via a UNC path.  It's only a mapped drive on the original DMZ server, which I did so that I could more easily provide the credentials to connect to the target server for the robocopy.  It appears that access isn't an issue during the restore that ultimately fails, because I also include the STATS parameter and it reports progress of between 10 percent and 40 percent completion before the error occurs.

Comment: Well sounds like flaky connectivity on top of that. Still, you can give a mapped drive to robocopy without ever referencing the path that way to SQL Server.

Comment: You can use the cmd.exe command `fc /b C:\some\local\path\file1.bak \\server\share\path\file2.bak` to do a manual binary comparison of the two backup files.

Comment: Aaron, I suspect you may be right about potentially flaky connectivity. Max,thanks for the suggestion to use the FC utility; I'll give that a try.

Comment: Just to follow up, the fc comparison did reveal at least 300 byte-pair differences between the original backup file and the robocopied version.  I believe a discussion with our network admins will be forthcoming.  Thanks again....

Answer (score 1):

Since the local copy of the backup file is validated successfully via `RESTORE VERIFYONLY`, the most likely cause of the issue is corruption of the target file while it is being copied over the network.

You can determine if the two copies of the backup file are binary-identical with the command-line utility [fc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490904.aspx):

```
fc /b C:\some\local\path\file1.bak \\server\share\path\file2.bak
```

Alternately, you could generate a cryptographic hash of each file, and see if the hashes are identical.  Microsoft offers a command-line tool for that purpose at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

If both files are binary-identical, the restore should complete without error.